# How can I implement in Angular an input box for IP Addresses like in Windows?

Tags: html, angular, ip, ip-address

I want to implement an input box so the user can enter an IP Address with Port (port can be optional). I want to make it like in Windows where there are 3 dots. I have tried with some mask components from the GitHub but when I want to enter the IP the input box will be like this: e.g. 10.1.40.__._ so I can't sumbit the result. Also I have tried to make 5 separate inputs box with dots between but I dosen't look good from an UX perspective.

Thank you for any help!

[image: Windows input box that I want to implement]
[image: This is what I've tried]

Comment: so u want to have masking like 10.__.__.__ this?

Comment: No. I want to have 3 dots so the users can enter the IP (without "_")

Answer (score 4):

you can use library for masking ip

> npm install --save ngx-mask

module

```
import {NgxMaskModule} from 'ngx-mask'

export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>);

@NgModule({
  (...)
  imports: [
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(options)
  ]
  (...)
})
```

html page

```
 <input mask="IP">
```

here is the reference https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask#readme

or

u can use pipe to transform the ip masking.